# why class B throws an error

Tags: c#-3.0

please explain me how this code is working and why it will trough an error in class B

```
public class A
    {
        protected int x;
        static void F(A a, B b) {
            a.x = 1;        // Ok
            b.x = 1;        // Ok
        }
    }
    public class B: A
    {
        static void F(A a, B b) {
            a.x = 1;        // Error, must access through instance of B
            b.x = 1;        // Ok
        }
    }
```

Comment: It says you have to acces through the instance of B so not through a.x = 1 in Public class B: A

Comment: But why when B is inheriting from the class A

Comment: i am confuse with th whole code, how in the static method the reference variables are passed and how the non static communicate with the static ...

Answer (score 2):

Code in `B` can only access a protected variable through an expression which has a compile-time type of `B` or some type derived from `B`. That's basically how protected access works.

From section 3.5.3 of the C# 4 language specification:

> When a protected instance member is accessed outside the program text of the class in which it is declared, and when a protected internal instance member is accessed outside the program text of the program in which it is declared, the access must take place within a class declaration that derives from the class in which it is declared. Furthermore, the access is required to take place *through* an instance of that derived class type or a class type constructed from it. This restriction prevents one derived class from accessing protected members of other derived classes, even when the members are inherited from the same base class.

Comment: Sir, that what i am reading from but i am just not getting it, please elaborate me on this ..one big confusion with me is how non static communicate with the static one ...such as when i access any non static in static context it throws an error then why not here

Comment: i should take it like a rule or there is some logic behind this which i am trying to explore

Answer (score 1):

> The `protected` keyword is a member
>   access modifier. A `protected` member
>   is accessible from within the class in
>   which it is declared, and from within
>   any `class` derived from the `class`
>   that declared this member.

```
public class A
    {
        public int x; 
        public static void F(A a, B b)
        {
            a.x = 1; 
            b.x = 1;
        }
    }
    public class B : A
    {
        public static void F(A a, B b)
        {
            a.x = 1; 
            b.x = 1;
        }
    }
```

Why I redefined it with `public` access modifier. `protected` modifier has restricted access to inherit `class` blocks.

```
Class A {
 protected int x = 0;
}
Class B : A {
 private void SomeFunc() {
  Console.WriteLine(this.x.ToString()); // This will work!
 }
}
```

But if you try to access `x` you'll get nothing in `B`.

```
B b = new B();
b.x; // Got nothing in IntelliSense
```

See we got the access of `x` in a function of `B` but it's instance has no access of `x`.

Comment: i want to know why B's instance has no access to x, while it is available in B due to inheritance please let elaborate me on this sir while it is accessible using the this key word how is it possible

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet Technically, the context of x is restricted into B ({ ....  }) blocks. It can be only access into these blocks.

Comment: not getting your above comment please explain me sir this is what troubling me to understand the whole coed

Comment: using this.x is same as the using b.x where the difference lying

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet It'll be same if you define it with public access modifier.

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet define it with protected access modifier restrict the usage of any reference to it's subclass.

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet read "Access for Derived Types with the protected Access Modifier" section in http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/lesson19.aspx